# Regex for no email and number (upto 5 digits allowed) and string can be added

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I want to apply validation that user can write string but cannot enter email id and number in continuous pattern upto 5 digits only.**
I am trying following not working:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{0,5}$
```

> **Like if user write :**

1. hello 12345 is good --- > True,
2. hello 134566 is bad ---- > false,
3. hello  +32444 is bad  --- > false,
4. hello 13233 is good , I have 12333 ---> true

thanks in advance

Comment: could you make some examples? (for match & no match)

Comment: Like : 
hello 12345 is good --- > True
hello 134566 is bad ---- > false
hello  +32444 is bad  --- > false
hello 13233 is good , I have 12333 ---> true

Comment: I have edit  cases in question u can check

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
^[A-z ,]*(([0-9]\s?){1,5})([A-z ,]*)(([A-z ,]+)(([0-9]\s?){1,5}))*$
```

Explanation:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `[A-z ,]*` matches the text before the number
- `(([0-9]\s?){1,5})` matches the number with spaces in it
- `([A-z ,]*)` matches the text after the first number
- `([A-z ,]+)(([0-9]\s?){1,5})` matches all other numbers with spaces in it and that ony, if ther ist text between the numbers
- `$` matches the end of the string

https://regex101.com/r/EbKsZG/2/tests

Comment: This regex not aspects space

Answer (score -1):

I have used following regex as solution for this:

```
^([a-zA-Z,\s]+[0-9\s]{0,5})+$
```

And sometimes people enter number with space specially phone number for restrict them, I use function on `Keyup` event:

```
valid(){
    this.commmentValid=false; //condition to show or not on html page
    var count=0;
    // Remove space from starting and end of string
    var a = (this.commentData.comment).trim(); 
    // Split each string value and form an array
    var m = a.split("");
    var preVal;
    // console.log(m)
    m.forEach(el => {
      console.log(el);
      var d= el.match(/\d+/);
      //Check if value is digit
      if(d){
        //Store previous value
        preVal=el;
        count++;
        if(count>=6){
          // Run when find phone number with and without space
          this.commmentValid=true;
        } 
      } 
      //If find space
      else if(el == " "){
        if(preVal){
          count++;
        }
      }
      //Check if string is ok
      else{
        count =0;
        preVal=0;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The regex match `12345 6789`, do you want that?